# Use npm_modules in Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, cordova, npm

I have just installed the `cordova-keychain` plugin using node package manager `npm i cordova-keychain`.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 as the IDE.  I can see that node has successfully installed the plugin into the `node_modules` folder in the root of my app however I cannot find any reference on how to use `node_modules` within the app.

When installing the generic corodva-device plugin etc I get reference to this plugin in the config file.  Do I simply move the `node_modules/cordova-keychain` folder into the `/plugins` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Very simple in the end. Double click config.xml file in the root of the project.  Click on plugins on the left and click on custom.  Click on the plugin folder in the node_modules folder and install.

Visual Studio will add the plugin to the project for you